# Finding total mass of a cone given density function.

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

[image]

My attempt:

I calculated density by substituting $x = 10$ in the given expression.

Used formula for volume of a cone to calculate the volume.

Worked out the mass using the formula M = D$\times$V.

My final answers for mass was approximately $261800kg$.

I doubt if this is the correct answer! I suspect that I am missing something. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Actually density varies with height so that's a wrong approach.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, I suspected that. So how do I approach this problem?

Comment: @MeghanC You need to integrate the density over the volume.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the base of the cone $C$ is located at the plane $z=0$, then, given a point $(x,y,z)$ of the cone, the density at that point is $z$, not $x$. So, the computation that you have to do is$$\int_C100(20-z)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^5\int_0^{10-2z}100(20-z)r\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\theta.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the height be $x$. The variation of radius can be found out as follows. At $x=10,r=0 $ and $x=0,r=5$ thus $r=c+kx$ solving we have $r=5-0.5x$ then $dm=pdV=100(20-x)\pi(5-0.5x)^2dx$ Now integrate this from $x=0-10$. You will get the total mass.

Comment: I don't understand your 3rd sentence, from when x = 10, r = 0....could you please explain in detail, especially variation of the radius up to the expression relating r and x.

Comment: that means at 10cm the radius is 0 as thats the end of the conical section. then we have r=c+kx . then we have two boundary condition and two unknowns(c,k) can you do it now?

Comment: Ok thanks, I get it. I have another question, how did you arrive at the formula for dV (without pi)?

Comment: As always I missed it.

Comment: Last question: when finding dV why divide by 3 if we are using a relation between r and x? I thought dV=$\pi r^2$dx where dV represents the volume of small discs of width dx and radius r.

Answer (score 1):

Split the cone into a series of thin disks each with volume ${\rm d}V =  \pi r^2\, {\rm d} x$ with $x = 0 \ldots h$ and $r = R \left(1-\tfrac{x}{h} \right)$.

$$ m = \int \rho(x) {\rm d}V = \pi R^2 \int \limits_0^h 100 (20-x)  
\left(1-\tfrac{x}{h} \right)^2 {\rm d}x $$